# GUI и многопоточность в Python: приостановка (pause) и перезапуск цикла в потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, gui, инспекция-кода, tkinter

Стало необходимо разобраться с многопоточностью в GUI. Прошу посмотреть на мой вариант и сказать, насколько он далек от правильной реализации, подсказать по поводу общих принципов управления потоками элементами GUI.
Програма используется для работы с терминалом

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')

bills = [0, 0, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 1, 2, 5, 10]

ev = threading.Event()
q = multiprocessing.Queue()

def polling_loop():
    while True:
        # у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом 'включении' потока
        ev.wait()# приостанавливаю поток
        # инициализирую купюроприемник
        ser.write(b'\x02\x03\x06\x30\x41\xb3') # здесь код, который выполняется один раз
        time.sleep(0.2)
        ser.write(b'\x02\x03\x0c\x34\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xb5\xc1')
        while ev.is_set():
            # а здесь код, который выполняется,
            # пока я не сброшу флаг с event`а кнопкой
            # здесь в цикле идет опрос на получение банкнот
            ser.write(b'\x02\x03\x06\x00\xc2\x82')
            ser.write(b'\x02\x03\x06\x33\xda\x81')
            time.sleep(0.2)
            if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                resp = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
                if resp[3] == 129:
                    q.put(bills[resp[4]])

def stop():
    ev.clear()

def start():
    ev.set()

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keywords):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **keywords)
        self.geometry('20x200')
        self.start = Button(text="start", command=lambda: start())
        self.stop = Button(text="stop", command=lambda: stop())
        self.stop.pack()
        self.start.pack()
        th2.start()
        # поток этот запускается сразу при инициализации

th2 = threading.Thread(target=polling_loop)
tk = Window()
tk.mainloop()
th2.join()
```

Comment: опишите словами, что вы ожидаете код должен делать и что вместо этого происходит. Если код по вашему работает правильно, а вы просто хотите отклик по конкретной реализации кода для конкретной задачи, то всё равно опишите *явно* что вы думаете он делает и добавьте метку [tag:инспекция-кода] (будьте уверены, что внешнее (наблюдаемое) поведение кода правильно (с вашей точки зрения), в  случае, если используете эту метку)

Comment: После закрытия окна поток продолжит работать. (А ещё рекомендую воткнуть в вопрос полностью рабочий код, чтобы таким как я не пришлось его додумывать самостоятельно)

Comment: Код работает как мне надо, но я не уверен, что мой вариант правелен, так-как с потоками раньше дел не имел, а писать по принципу "работает и ладно" мне не очень нравится

Comment: связанные вопросы: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/4279), [How to stop a looping thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18018033/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import threading, tkinter, time

class Window(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('20x200')
        self.is_run = False
        tkinter.Button(text="start", command=lambda: self.is_run or 
                                             threading.Thread(target=self.run).start()).pack()
        tkinter.Button(text="stop", command=self.stop).pack()

    def stop(self): self.is_run = False
    def run(self):
        self.is_run = True
        print('у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока')
        while self.is_run:
            print('а здесь код, который выполняется')
            time.sleep(1)
        print('выход')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

out:

```
у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока
а здесь код, который выполняется
а здесь код, который выполняется
а здесь код, который выполняется
выход
```

или

```
import threading, tkinter, time, queue

class SThread(threading.Thread):
    '''worker поток'''
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print('thread.run')
        while True:
            cmd = self.queue.get(timeout=10)
            print(cmd)
            if cmd is None:
                break
            cmd['out'] = cmd['target'](*cmd.get('args', ()), **cmd.get('kwargs', {}))
            self.queue.task_done()

class Window(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('20x200')
        self.is_run = False
        self.thread = SThread()
        tkinter.Button(text="start", command=lambda: self.is_run or self.thread.queue.put(
            dict(target=self.run))).pack()
        tkinter.Button(text="stop", command=self.stop).pack()

    def stop(self): self.is_run = False
    def run(self):
        print('у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока')
        self.is_run = True
        while self.is_run:
            print('а здесь код, который выполняется')
            time.sleep(1)
        print('выход')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

out:

```
thread.run
{'target': <bound method Window.run of <__main__.Window object at 0x01F19710>>}
у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока
а здесь код, который выполняется
а здесь код, который выполняется
выход
```

или

```
import threading, tkinter, time

class Window(tkinter.Tk, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.wait = 1
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()
        self.geometry('20x200')
        tkinter.Button(text="start", command=self.Start).pack()
        tkinter.Button(text="stop", command=self.Stop).pack()
        def destroy():
            self.wait = -1
            time.sleep(1)
            self.destroy()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroy)

    def Stop(self): self.wait = 1
    def Start(self): self.wait = 0
    def run(self):
        print('thread.start')
        while self.wait >= 0:
            if self.wait: time.sleep(self.wait)
            else:
                self._target = self.work
                self._args = ()
                self._kwargs = {}
                super().run()
        print('thread.stop')

    def work(self):
        print('у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока')
        while not self.wait:
            print('а здесь код, который выполняется')
            time.sleep(1)
        print('выход')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

out:

```
thread.start
у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока
а здесь код, который выполняется
а здесь код, который выполняется
выход
у меня есть часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом включении потока
а здесь код, который выполняется
выход
thread.stop
```

Метод super().run()

```
def run(self):
    """Method representing the thread's activity.

    You may override this method in a subclass. The standard run() method
    invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor as the
    target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken
    from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

    """
    try:
        if self._target:
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    finally:
        # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
        # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
        del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
```

Comment: Этот вариант мной рассматривался, но он не подходит, так-как поток не может быть запущен второй раз.

Comment: почему нельзя, запускайте его так: threading.Thread(target=ThrObj.run).start(). Достаточно запустить у объекта метод run повторно.

Comment: `threads can only be started once`

Comment: вы непоняли. Метод .start() запускается один раз. Вся "работа" в методе .run(). Остановили run, работа остановилась, запустили - продолжилась

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Вы сэкономили мне кучу времени

Comment: @Putch: код в вашем вопросе и код в ответе разные вещи выполняют. Код в ответе запускает каждый раз *новый* поток по нажатию на start кнопку и останавливает запущенный поток в конце итерации по нажатию на stop кнопку. Код в вопросе использует *один* поток и вложенные циклы. Разницу в поведении можно увидеть если на кнопку start два раза нажать (код в вопросе запустит два потока вместо одного).

Comment: @Putch поправка: код в *ответе* запустит два потока если два раза start кнопку нажать. Код в *вопросе* запустит только один поток. Код  в ответе нужно расширить, чтобы избежать запуска более одного потока одновременно.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa Буду очень признателен, если поясните почему run вызывается через super, а не через self

Comment: тк вызывается метод run, унаследованный от класса threading.Thread, и который переопределен self.run http://pythoner.name/documentation/library/functions/super

Comment: `Thread.run()` не должен более одного раза запускаться. Вы не должны внутренние недокументированные поля, такие как `self._target` изменять.

Comment: по какой причине? впрочем лучше заменить super().run() на чтото типа cmd['out'] = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

Использование фонового потока для исполнения блокирующего кода в GUI программе и `threading.Event` для приостановки/запуска кода из другого потока вполне оправдано. Хотя, если метод `Event.wait(timeout)` не нужен в вашем случае, то даже простой `True`/`False` флаг мог бы быть использован вместо `threading.Event()`.

Иногда отдельный поток вообще не нужен: работу с I/O можно встроить в цикл событий GUI. Tkinter предоставляет [`Tk.createfilehandler()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#file-handlers) на некоторых системах. [Пример кода, который использует `createfilehandler()`, чтобы читать вывод из подпрограммы](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978). Для сравнения, [пример кода, который использует фоновый поток для той же задачи](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682520/4279)—обратите внимание как [`Tk.after()` метод](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) вызывается для создания цикла в GUI потоке (без блокирования самого потока).

Полный пример, который приостанавливает и перезапускает цикл в отдельном потоке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import queue
import threading

def restartable_loop(restarted, results):
    while restarted.wait(): # wait until the loop is restarted
        results.put("часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз "
                    "при каждом 'включении' потока")
        while restarted.is_set(): # while it is running
            results.put('код, который выполняется, '
                        'пока флаг restarted не переустановлен')
        results.put(None) # mark the end of the current batch

q = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
restarted = threading.Event()
run_loop = restarted.set
pause_loop = restarted.clear

print('запускаем поток')
threading.Thread(target=restartable_loop, args=[restarted, q], daemon=True).start()
try:
    q.get(timeout=.5)
except queue.Empty: # ничего не должны получить пока цикл не запущен
    pass
else:
    assert 0, "never happens"

for _ in range(2): # повторим пару раз для демонстрации
    print('запускаем цикл')
    run_loop()
    print(q.get()) # получаем результат
    print(q.get()) # получаем результат

    print('приостанавливаем цикл')
    pause_loop()
    print('считаем сколько результатов получили:', len(list(iter(q.get, None))))
```

#### Пример вывода

```
запускаем поток
запускаем цикл
часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом 'включении' потока
код, который выполняется, пока флаг restarted не переустановлен
приостанавливаем цикл
считаем сколько результатов получили: 11
запускаем цикл
часть кода, которая должна выполнятся один раз при каждом 'включении' потока
код, который выполняется, пока флаг restarted не переустановлен
приостанавливаем цикл
считаем сколько результатов получили: 9
```

Замечания по коду:

- используйте `queue.Queue` вместо `multiprocessing.Queue` (потоки и процессы это разные вещи)
- не используйте `time.sleep()` в коде со многими потоками, если можно найти более явные механизмы синхронизации между потоками. Например, в примере кода в ответе используется [блокирующий `Queue.put()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put). Благодаря `Queue(maxsize=10)`, код в фоновом потоке приостановится, если основной поток не успевает элементы из очереди вовремя вынимать
- используйте `command=start`, вместо `command=lambda: start()`. `lambda` не нужна в данном случае—в Питоне функции можно передавать как есть в качестве параметров в другие функции
- в общем случае, предпочитайте делегирование вместо наследования. Например, [`tkinter.Tk()` передан как параметр в `ShowProcessOutputDemo` в примере кода, указанном выше,](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978) вместо использования `Tk` как базового класса: наследование создаёт слишком тесную связь между базовым и дочерними классами (например, приходится думать о конфликтах имён нечастных атрибутов класса)—логику приложения и логику многократно используемого GUI элемента (окна) может иметь смысл отдельно держать.

Comment: Благодарю вас за участие.Это все для меня все еще актуально поэтому большое спасибо